# Django custom registration fails to store certain fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-auth

I have a django rest project wherein I have customized user model to fit my needs. I also have created a custom serializer to add more fields like address, phone number etc to be stored during registration. I am using django-rest-auth for login and registration. Browsable API looks like follows:

[image]

The registration is successful, however it fails to store address and user type.

My custom user model:

```
    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

  def _create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
    now = timezone.now()
    if not username:
      raise ValueError(_('The given username must be set'))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
             is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
             is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
             date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

  def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False,
                 **extra_fields)

  def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
    user=self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True,
                 **extra_fields)
    user.is_active=True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
    help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters'),
    validators=[
      validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w.@+-]+$'), _('Enter a valid username.'), _('invalid'))
    ])
  first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
  email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255, unique=True)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
    help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'))
  is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
    help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
  date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
  receive_newsletter = models.BooleanField(_('receive newsletter'), default=False)
  birth_date = models.DateField(_('birth date'), auto_now=False, null=True)
  address = models.CharField(_('address'), max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
  phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
  phone_number = models.CharField(_('phone number'), validators=[phone_regex], max_length=30, blank=True, null=True) # validators should be a list

  USER_TYPES = (
    ('Farmer', 'Farmer'),
    ('Windmill owner', 'Windmill owner'),
    ('Solar panel owner', 'Solar panel owner'),)
  user_type = models.CharField(_('user type'), choices=USER_TYPES, max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]

  objects = UserManager()

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')

  def get_full_name(self):
    full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    return full_name.strip()

  def get_short_name(self):
    return self.first_name

  def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

My register serializer:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
address = serializers.CharField(max_length=500, required=True, write_only=True)
#user_type = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

user_type = serializers.ChoiceField(
choices=[('Farmer', 'Farmer'),('Windmill owner', 'Windmill owner'),('Solar panel owner', 'Solar panel owner'),],
style={'base_template': 'radio.html'},
required=True, write_only=True)


password1 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
password2 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

def validate_email(self, email):
    email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
    if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
        if email and email_address_exists(email):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                _("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
    return email

def validate_password1(self, password):
    return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

def validate(self, data):
    if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            _("The two password fields didn't match."))
    return data

def get_cleaned_data(self):
    return {
        'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
        'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
        'address': self.validated_data.get('address', ''),
        'user_type': self.validated_data.get('user_type', ''),
        'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
        'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
    }

def save(self, request):
    adapter = get_adapter()
    user = adapter.new_user(request)
    self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
    adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
    setup_user_email(request, user, [])
    user.save()
    return user
```

What exactly is going wrong? Why these fields are not stored?